# Why won't image auto refresh

Tags: javascript, image, timer, refresh

Trying to get images to refresh themselves with javascript a set number of times, then stop (to avoid large cache generation).  This code won't function though, so not sure what's missing?

```
<script>
var c = 0;
function fnSetTimer()
{
document.getElementById('refreshimage1').src='http://68.116.42.142:8080/cam_4.jpg?\'+new Date().getMilliseconds();
var t = setTimeout(fnSetTimer,5000);
c=c+1; 
if(c>5) 
clearTimeout(t); 
} 
</script>
<img src="http://68.116.42.142:8080/cam_4.jpg"; id="refreshimage1" onload="fnSetTimer()" width="400" />
```

However, this code does work:

```
<img src="http://68.116.42.142:8080/cam_4.jpg"; id="refreshimage2" onload="setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'refreshimage2\').src=\'http://68.116.42.142:8080/cam_4.jpg?\'+new Date().getMilliseconds()', 5000)" width="400" />
```

So if you place both side by side, the bottom image will refresh (indefinitely), but the top image just loads once and never refreshes.  Any thoughts what I missed in the top code?

Comment: do you really have `?\'+` in your code? change it to `?'+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the function re-loads the image, which calls the function, which re-loads the image...

You also had a problem with the image url - '\' is used to escape special characters, if you want a slash you need two - '\\'

**PUT THIS IN YOUR HEADER**

```
<script language="javascript">

function fnSetTimer(image, src, counter, limit)
{
    image.onload = null;

    if(counter < limit)
    {
        counter++;
        setTimeout(function(){ fnSetTimer(image, src, counter, limit); },5000);
        image.src= src+ '?\\'+new Date().getMilliseconds();
        alert(counter); // show frame number
    }
} 
</script>
```

**PUT THIS IN THE BODY**

```
<img src="http://68.116.42.142:8080/cam_4.jpg"; id="refreshimage1" onload="fnSetTimer(this, this.src, 0, 5);" width="400" />
```

This should fix it for you - it only fires onLoad once and then loops through 5 times, and you should be able to edit the image tag in Wordpress, etc.

**MAKE SURE YOU GIVE EACH IMAGE A DIFFERENT ID**

Comment: Thank you! That worked, when I put the script in the header.  Unfortunately I'm using a wordpress site, which means I have to have the script loaded into the header.php, or call a .js file.  I am trying to make something I can edit on each page, so the script cannot go into the HEADER section unfortunately.  And, this code doesn't seem to function when I put it all in the BODY.  If you know of a way to make this refresh image stop after x times work, and all called from the BODY, please let me know? Thank you for the great answer too-

Comment: - I've updated it, put the function wherever you like - it doesn't matter.

You can edit the image tag in Wordpress.

Comment: One last question- what would it take to be able to have multiple images refresh on the same page?  As it is, only the first refreshes, even if the rest have a unique ID.

Comment: Why didn't you ask that in your original question?

Comment: I should have asked that... I blame it on a new baby and sleep deprivation.  Great logic, works super.  Thank you again